# Class 'list' does not define '__mod__', so the '%' operator cannot be used

Tags: python, fabric

I need to dynamically set a hosts env in a Fabric task.

I have tried this:

```
env.hosts = ['%s'] % server_ip_var
```

But I get this error:

> Class 'list' does not define '**mod**', so the '%' operator cannot be
>   used on its instances less...
>
> This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to
>   dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but
>   useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported
>   better than instance items.

Comment: remove the bracket: `env.hosts = '%s' % server_ip_var`. Or use parenthesis: `env.hosts = ('%s') % server_ip_var`

Comment: `%` is a string operator: `env.hosts = [ '%s'%server_ip_var ]` if you need a list of string(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are asking, but converting an object to a string can be achieved in various ways. One possibility is to use the `str()` function if your variable can be converted to a string:

```
env.hosts = [str(server_ip_var)]
```

Another (better) way would be to use the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
env.hosts = ["{}".format(server_ip_var)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you can subclass `list`:

```
class FormattableList(list):
    def __mod__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return list(x.__mod__(*args, **kwargs) for x in self)


print(FormattableList(['a: %s', 'b: %s']) % 123)
```